# How do i show all numbers that have a 4 digit representation in the 8th base(numerical base 8?)?

Tags: c++, numeric, digits

I would put a code here if i had any idea how to do this. However, i have the code for just the numerical base:

```
using namespace std;
int n,i,s,rest,cat;
int main()
{

    cin>>n;

    s=0;
    i=1;
    while(n>0)
    {
        rest=n%8;
        cout<<"rest: "<<endl<<rest<<endl;
        cat=n/8;
        cout<<"cat: "<<endl<<cat<<endl;
        s=s+rest*i;
        cout<<"s: "<<endl<<s<<endl;
        i=i*10;
        cout<<"i: "<<endl<<i<<endl;
        n=cat;
    }
    cout<<"s="<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this include negative integers or just positive integers?

Comment: And are you outputting these numbers in base8 representation or base10 representation?

Comment: base8 is called `octal`

Comment: I see 2 different approaches, go from 1 to `n` and test if number satisfies the constraint. Or build the "series" `0XX4` `0X4X` `04XX` (So 0004, 0014, 0024, 0034, 004X, 0054, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the smallest number represented by 4 digits in octal? What's the largest number represented by 4 digits in octal? You can figure this out by hand, then loop through the values.

On paper:

```
1000_(base8) = X_(base10) // solve for X
7777_(base8) = Y_(base10) // solve for Y
```

Then in your code, just loop between these two numbers. This will output the *octal* form of all numbers between octal 1000 and octal 7777 (inclusive).

```
std::cout << std::oct; // set all integer outputs on std::cout to octal
for (unsigned int i = X; i <= Y; i++)
    std::cout << i << "\n"; 

std::cout << std::dec; // set it back to decimal
```

You will need to `#include <iomanip>` to use the stream format specifier `std::oct`.

If you want your program to calculate an arbitrary octal number from a string, you can use [`std::stoull`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul). This gives the unsigned integer that represents octal 1000:

```
int X = std::stoul("1000", 0, 8);
```

If you want to use math, then you can recognize that the smallest `base-n` number that takes up `m` digits is `n**(m-1)`, where `**` represents exponentiation (except in the edge-case where you have a 1-digit number, in which case the smallest number that can be represented is `0`).

The largest `base-n` number that takes up `m` digits is `(n**m) - 1`.

When calculating exponents, you may be tempted to use `pow`. Don't do that. That is for floating point numbers. Calculate `n**m` for integers using a loop.

Comment: I understand that values are from 1000 to 7777, i just dont get how i can integrate the loop in this code using these "simple" notions and how to display them.

Comment: You never answered my question if you need to output these in base8 or base10. That might be contributing to some of the confusion here. I'm under the assumption you need to print out the base10 representations of these numbers. (i.e. I assume your output needs to be `512` thru `4095`)

Comment: No, i just need the base8 representation. Sorry for not answering beforehand.

Comment: I edited my answer. You do everything the same, but before you output the number you send `std::oct` to the output stream.